# How to add a calculated field to a Microsoft Access query that equals the minimum value of the previous column field

Tags: ms-access, computed-column, fields

I have a simple query on a very complex query that reads:

```sql
SELECT Query1.Rdate, Query1.Rank, Query1.Score
FROM Query1;
```

```
                                                                                                                                It returns:
```

| RDate | Rank | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2022 | 5 | 0.9 |
| 2/1/2022 | 3 | 0.6 |
| 2/1/2022 | 1 | 0.3 |
| 2/1/2022 | 2 | 0.8 |
| 2/1/2022 | 4 | 0.2 |

I need a second query that uses this query to return:

| RDate | Rank | Score | MinScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2022 | 5 | 0.9 | 0.2 |
| 2/1/2022 | 3 | 0.6 | 0.2 |
| 2/1/2022 | 1 | 0.3 | 0.2 |
| 2/1/2022 | 2 | 0.8 | 0.2 |
| 2/1/2022 | 4 | 0.2 | 0.2 |

where the new column of 0.2 represents the Minimum value of the previous column.
I know I can write a query that will return a single column of the value 0.2 and then ANOTHER QUERY to combine that column with my original query. But I have over 200 original queries. I would then end up with over 600 queries. I don't want to go down that path if I can avoid it.

Comment: What's the query you have used so far? And please provide scripts for sample data.